# Apache Flink RollingFileAppender

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Apache Flink v1.2. I wanted to switch to a rolling file appender to avoid huge log files containing data for several days. However it doesn't seem to work. I adapted the log4j Configuration (`log4j.properties`) as follows:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a'.log'
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex = 15
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
```

First it complains it cannot find `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`.  So I switch it to `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender` and then it says `RollingPolicy` and `DatePattern` are not valid attributes for the `RollingFileAppender`.

Did anyone else encounter same issues / can you suggest what's wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `RollingFileAppender` you first have to add the `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` to your classpath (e.g. adding it to Flink's `lib` folder).

Next you have to configure it and specify a `FileNamePattern` before specifying the `RollingPolicy`. With the following `log4j.properties` file I can use the `RollingFileAppender`.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/log.%d{yyyyMMdd-HHmm}.log
log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-60c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I also found the "log4j-extras" dependency not sure why it's not included by default.