# Flink write empty file

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink (v. 1.4) which read data from Kafka topic and write it to to avro  to HDFS. Sometimes (once per 2 week) I get an empty file, I cant find some exceptions in logs.
Could you help me please is it possible that cause is old Flink version and where I can find the description the same cases.

Comment: As far as I know, bulk formats flush the data to underlying storage on checkpoint. Can it be possible that the checkpointing interval is less frequent then data appearance in Kafka topic ?

Comment: I think no, because  checkpointing interval is 10 minutes and new data appear in topic every second.

Comment: Could you check if the checkpoint takes longer than your bulk format flushes? If the checkpoint requires alignment and blocks data flow, I'd imagine that it's possible that no data arrives at the sink during the duration of one bucket.

Comment: In general, upgrading your Flink version should definitively help as there is a good chance that any potential bug has been fixed.

Comment: Are you using Flink log rolling policy? Because it can be the ssize is not set. If you are not using it you can use and set the rolling policy based on the size. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45819410/2096986